# Javascript- randomize 8 groups of 4

Tags: javascript, arraylist

This is my code for my final, objective is to create 8 groups of 4 in each group and than, ask what country are you looking for, than tell person which group they are in.

```
/*This program will create the 2026 world cup groups (8 groups 0f 4) with the countries for each group
being randomly seleceted from the list of countries*/

println("2026 World Cup Groups");
println("     ");
println(" ");

var countries = ["Mexico", "Brazil", "Poland", "Argentina", "Uruguay",
                 "England", "Spain", "Germany", "Portugal", "Morocco", 
                 "Croatia", "Cameroon", "USA", "Ecuador", "Japan", "Saudi Arabia",
                 "Canada", "Senegal", "Netherlands", "Costa Rica", "Colombia", 
                 "Wales", "Belgium", "Serbia", "Italy" , "France", "Australia",
                 "Denmark", "Tunisia", "Ghana", "Korea Republic", "Qatar"];

             
    


function start(){

    var groupA = [];
    var groupB = [];
    var groupC = [];
    var groupD = [];
    var groupE = [];
    var groupF = [];
    var groupG = [];
    var groupH = [];  
    

    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        groupA.push(groupRandomizer(countries));
        groupB.push(groupRandomizer(countries));
        groupC.push(groupRandomizer(countries));
        groupD.push(groupRandomizer(countries));
        groupE.push(groupRandomizer(countries));
        groupF.push(groupRandomizer(countries));
        groupG.push(groupRandomizer(countries));
        groupH.push(groupRandomizer(countries));

    }
    println("Group A:");
    println(groupA);
    println(" ");
    println("Group B:");
    println(groupB);
    println(" ");
    println("Group C:");
    println(groupC);
    println(" ");
    println("Group D");
    println(groupD);
    println(" ");
    println("Group E:");
    println(groupE);
    println(" ");
    println("Group F:");
    println(groupF);
    println(" ");
    println("Group G:");
    println(groupG);
    println(" ");
    println("Group H:");
    println(groupH);
    println(" ");



   var lookForCountry = readLine("What country are you looking for? " );
/*this if function will take the country that you inputed in lookForCountry and
  return  a line telling you what group that country is located in*/

   if(lookForCountry == groupA){
       println(lookForCountry + "is in group A");
   }


}


function groupRandomizer(arr){

    var randomizer = Randomizer.nextInt(countries.indexOf[0],
                                         countries.indexOf[31]);

    return arr[randomizer];

}
```

this is the code, [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiRRj.jpg)

if you guys know what I am doing wrong please let me know. I would appreciate it.
Again
the objective of this code is to randomize 8 groups, each group containing 4 countrys
than ask which country are they looking for
than display where that country is.

Comment: `println`? where is this code being run? Where is `Randomizer.nextInt` defined?

Comment: You know you can take a screenshot like without a phone right

Answer (score 0):

If you can change everything in the code, this version seems simple

```
let countries = ["Mexico", "Brazil", "Poland", "Argentina", "Uruguay",
                 "England", "Spain", "Germany", "Portugal", "Morocco", 
                 "Croatia", "Cameroon", "USA", "Ecuador", "Japan", "Saudi Arabia",
                 "Canada", "Senegal", "Netherlands", "Costa Rica", "Colombia", 
                 "Wales", "Belgium", "Serbia", "Italy" , "France", "Australia",
                 "Denmark", "Tunisia", "Ghana", "Korea Republic", "Qatar"];

countries = countries.map( name => ({name, group: null}) );


const order = new Array(countries.length).fill().map( (_, i) => i);

const groups = [[]];

for( let i of order ) {
    let currentGroup = groups[groups.length-1];
    if( currentGroup.length === 4 ) {
        currentGroup = [];
        groups.push(currentGroup);
    }
    countries[i].group = groups.length;
    currentGroup.push(countries[i]);
}

function findInGroup(name) {
    const found = countries.find( c => c.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(name.toLowerCase() ) );
    if( !found ) {
        console.log('Cannot found');
        return;
    }
    console.log(found);
}

console.log(groups);
findInGroup('Mexi');
```